# SSD changes disk file system automatically

Tags: windows, ssd

I'm using `AMD Radeon R7 480Gb SSD`. I don't know why, but yesterday laptop crashed. It stopped response and I turned it off manually (by holdin power button). After this I attempted to start system, but `Windows` was not started. Only the Windows logo screens *without loading*.

> P.S. It's not first time happening. For the first time I changed disk file system with specific tools, so I can do it again. But I want to solve ***from the root***?

Thanks for any attention.

Best regards,
Mirjalal.

Comment: Based on the information you provided, we cannot really tell you what caused it, you didn't provide specific enough errors for us to even guess.  You didn't even tell us what you did exactly to fix the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound there is(are) no any error and/or warning(s).
For first time I changed file system from `unknown` to `NTFS`, deleted all partitions and created a fresh one. After these operations I installed OS. (this happened 1 month ago)

Comment: Can you boot into [Safe Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_mode)? Alternatively, I suggest you make a [bootable USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB) (e.g. an [Ubuntu Live USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)) and check if you can correct issues with the partition table of at least recover your files.

Comment: If your file-system magically became corrupted multiple times (which is what's happening), then try a new drive.

Answer (score 1):

If your disk is repeatedly corrupting itself without you doing anything to it, then you need to replace the drive.

If it happened once, I would have suggested some form of malware/virus - but unless you are installing pirated or dodgy software after each rebuild - its less likely to be a repeated cause.

If this machine was ok before you installed the SSD, this would also rule out something to do with the motherboard/raid controller - however this would be fairly unlikely as you seem to only have 1 drive and do not mention any form of controller in your question.

Comment: thanks for attention and answer. but it's new drive. I bought it 4-5 months ago. And this situation happened 2 months ago. And I don't know how to fix it.